# Read txt file and remove duplicates

Tags: python, txt

I do open a txt file with the below code and getting the following output:
['MUR,MUR,COP,COP,COP,COP,COP']

```
# opening the file in read mode
my_file = open("my_txt.txt", "r")

# reading the file
data = my_file.read()

# replacing end splitting the text 
# when newline ('\n') is seen.
data_into_list = data.split("\n")
print(data_into_list)
my_file.close()
```

How can I remove the duplicates?

Comment: instead of `data.split("\n")` use `set(data.splitlines())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `set()`

```
data_into_list = list(set(data.split("\n")))
```

I suggest you look at this question if you need to preserve order [How do I remove duplicates from a list, while preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order)

```
data_into_list = list(dict.fromkeys(data.split("\n")))
```

Answer (score 2):

use built-in data type python, call : **set**
Set items are unordered, unchangeable, and do not allow duplicate values.

for example :

```
data = ['MUR,MUR,COP,COP,COP,COP,COP']

>>> data_new = list(data[0].split(','))
>>> data_new
['MUR', 'MUR', 'COP', 'COP', 'COP', 'COP', 'COP']
>>> data_uniq = list(set(data_new))
>>> data_uniq
['MUR', 'COP']
>>>
```

Comment: `set` is not a function, though.

Comment: @KlasŠ.thanks for the correction, i have edited my answer

Comment: IF I using the abobe code I am getting the following TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @Yvar, can you add also the example data which reproduce that error, and the complete error, please?

Comment: @HenroSutrisnoTanjung After I restarted the kernel your code works fine. Thanks a lot for your support.